# Padding not 0 on float:right

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an image go ALL the way right on a DIV but it's not happening:\

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<style>* { margin:0;padding:0; }
#login {
background:red;
width:200px;
xpadding:5px;
}
#login a, #login a:visited {
color:blue;
text-decoration:none;
font:12px verdana;
}
</style>
    <title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<body>



<div id="login"><div style="float:right;margin-right:5px;"><img src="https://si0.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_0_normal.png" /> </div>

<div style="float:right;color:red;text-align:right;"><a href="#">@Testing</a><br /><a href="?wipe=1">Logout</a></div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Try that on say... http://htmledit.squarefree.com/ that and you'll see red is still visible on the right-hand side of the border when it should float all the way right.

Comment: I dont exactly get what you need, as here i think the code does exactly what it is supposed to do. Everything is inside the `login` div, and that div is 200px, so everything is within the 200px width. And the `float:right` has floated it to the right most part of the div

Comment: remove margin-right:5px;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<div style="float:right,margin-right:5px;">`

***margin-right:5px***

Comment: +1, even though it's competing with my answer. I like the phrasing of this answer best.

Comment: +1 to all 3 of you guys, first with the correct answer. I had to play around with it to find it.

Comment: @Jahkr: Everyone here has made exactly this sort of mistake over and over again, fresh eyes are great for spotting the obvious. Live and learn and all that.

Answer (score 4):

Take off the `margin-right:5px;` on your inner `DIV` around the image.

`<div style="float:right;">`

Answer (score 3):

Well the float has "margin-right:5px;" in its style attribute. That's causing a 5-pixel margin on the right... if you remove that, it will go all the way to the right.

You asked to make the image go all the way to the right on a div, but you didn't say which div. The img *is* already all the way to the right on its immediate parent, but that div is 5 pixels from the right of its parent ("login").

Comment: @mu is too short Lol, didn't realise sportsmanship was a badge. I should do that more often ;)

Answer (score 1):

Setting the margin to 0 inside your image div gets the image all the way over.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<style>body { margin:0;padding:0; }
#login {
background:red;
width:200px;
xpadding:5px;
}
#login a, #login a:visited {
color:blue;
text-decoration:none;
font:12px verdana;
}
</style>
    <title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<body>



<div id="login"><div style="float:right;margin-right:0px;"><img src="https://si0.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_0_normal.png" /> </div>

<div style="float:right;color:red;text-align:right;"><a href="#">@Testing</a><br /><a href="?wipe=1">Logout</a></div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like that:

```
<div id="login"><div style="float:right;padding-left:10px;"><img src="https://si0.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_0_normal.png" /> </div>
```

[image]